# How to get a "minimalist" array of objects from an array of objects with a pletora of attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array, like this:

```
let x = [
    {id: 1, name: 'A', age: 34.. lots of other properties}, 
    {id: 2, name: 'B', age: 17.. }, 
    {id: 3, name: 'C', age: 54.. }
]
```

How can I get this output from it:

```
let output = [
    {id: 1, name: 'A'}, 
    {id: 2, name: 'B'}, 
    {id: 3, name: 'C'}
]
```

I mean, I can iterate throut it, and push new objects into a new array. But I was thinking if there's a better way to do it..

Comment: `let output = x.map(({ id, name }) => ({ id, name }))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map`

```js
let x = [
    {id: 1, name: 'A', age: 34.,}, 
    {id: 2, name: 'B', age: 17., }, 
    {id: 3, name: 'C', age: 54., }
];
console.log(x.map(({id, name}) => ({id, name})));
```

Answer (score 3):

More generally, for any set of attributes, the idea is called “pick” and  "pluck" in lodash and underscore...

```js
let x = [
    {id: 1, name: 'A', age: 34 }, 
    {id: 2, name: 'B', age: 17 }, 
    {id: 3, name: 'C', age: 54 }
]

function pick(object, ...attributes) {
  const filtered = Object.entries(object).filter(([k, v]) => attributes.includes(k))
  return Object.fromEntries(filtered);
}

function pluck(array, ...attributes) {
  return array.map(el => pick(el, ...attributes))
}

console.log(pluck(x, 'id', 'name'))
```